# Android: Uploading image without losing Exif data

Tags: android, exif

In our app users have been uploading millions of images for years using (roughly) this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(postFilePath, bmOptions);
Bitmap roughBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(postFilePath, bmOptions);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

roughBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());

int fileSize = stream.toByteArray().length;
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(fileSize));
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(fileSize);

...

if (fis != null) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[10240];

    int read;

    while ((read = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
        os.write(buf, 0, read);
        totalBytesRead += read;
        if (uploadProgressListener != null) {
            try {
                uploadProgressListener.onBytesUploaded(read);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(e);
            }
        }
    }

    fis.close();
}
```

Recently we saw the need to preserve the `Exif` data of uploaded images. The problem is that the image Exif data is lost when compressing the bitmap. I thought of using `ExifInterface` for extracting this data from the original file:

```
ExifInterface oldExif = new ExifInterface(postFilePath);
String value = oldExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
```

..and then adding it to the InputStream `fis` and then continue uploading the file. The problem is that `ExifInterface` **cannot save Exif data to an InputStream**.

How can Exif data be retained in the images when they'er uploaded to the server?

**It's not a duplicate:**
Just to clarify deeper, I've tried using the suggested `duplicate question` by using this method:

```
public static void copyExif(String originalPath, InputStream newStream) throws IOException {

    String[] attributes = new String[]
            {
                    ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE
            };

    ExifInterface oldExif = new ExifInterface(originalPath);
    ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(newStream);

    if (attributes.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
            String value = oldExif.getAttribute(attributes[i]);
            if (value != null)
                newExif.setAttribute(attributes[i], value);
        }
        newExif.saveAttributes();
    }
}
```

.. but got the exception `java.io.IOException: ExifInterface does not support saving attributes for the current input.` after `newExif.saveAttributes();` because I'm trying to save the attributes to an InputStream. How else can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Exif data after bitmap compression in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762133/how-to-save-exif-data-after-bitmap-compression-in-android)

Comment: I have seen this one. Went after the suggestion, but as I wrote `ExifInterface` can only save to images, which is my problem here, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see your problem. Create an `ExifInterface` for both your original file and the compressed one (create a new `Bitmap` from the outputstream) and use `exifComp.setAttribute(TAG_..., exifOrig(TAG_...));` and save it with `exifComp.save()`. Afterwards, get the outputstream from the compressed file.

Comment: @amuttsch, do you mean to save the compressed file first, then save the exif attributes to it and then read a stream from it again? I can du that, but was hoping to avoid having to save the compressed file to the storage in the process.

Comment: You can get an inputstream from an outputstream and use `BitmapFactory`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286599/get-an-input-stream-from-an-output-stream

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**My solution:**

As *@amuttsch* and *@CommonsWare* suggested, I:

1. saved the scaled/compressed bitmap to a temp file
2. copied the exif from the original file to the temp file
3. converted the temp file to a byte array and sent it to upload

.. then I found out that the server strips the Exif again while generating image variants :-P but that's another story which server guys are now working to correct.

*Main code:*

```
...
// Copy original Exif to scaledBitmap
String tempFilePath = getTempFilePath(postFilePath);
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFilePath);
    scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
    copyExif(postFilePath, tempFilePath);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Get stream from temp (exif loaded) file
File tempFile = new File(tempFilePath);
byte[] byteFile = readFile(tempFile);
fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteFile);

// Remove the temp file
boolean deleted = tempFile.delete();

// Finalize
int fileSize = byteFile.length;
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(fileSize));
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(fileSize);
...
```

*getTempFilePath():*

```
private String getTempFilePath(String filename) {
    String temp = "_temp";
    int dot = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    String ext = filename.substring(dot + 1);

    if (dot == -1 || !ext.matches("\\w+")) {
        filename += temp;
    } else {
        filename = filename.substring(0, dot) + temp + "." + ext;
    }

    return filename;
}
```

*copyExif():*

```
public static void copyExif(String originalPath, String newPath) throws IOException {

    String[] attributes = new String[]
            {
                    ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME,
                    ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE
            };

    ExifInterface oldExif = new ExifInterface(originalPath);
    ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(newPath);

    if (attributes.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
            String value = oldExif.getAttribute(attributes[i]);
            if (value != null)
                newExif.setAttribute(attributes[i], value);
        }
        newExif.saveAttributes();
    }
}
```

*readFile():*

```
public static byte[] readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    // Open file
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    try {
        // Get and check length
        long longlength = f.length();
        int length = (int) longlength;
        if (length != longlength)
            throw new IOException("File size >= 2 GB");
        // Read file and return data
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        f.readFully(data);
        return data;
    } finally {
        f.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that the image Exif data is lost when compressing the bitmap

The EXIF data is lost when reading in the `Bitmap`. A `Bitmap` has no EXIF tags.

> How can Exif data be retained in the images when they'er uploaded to the server?

Stop reading in the `Bitmap`. Just upload the contents of `postFilePath` as-is. It will contain whatever EXIF tags it contains.

My assumption is that you are reading in the `Bitmap` in the hope that saving it again in 70% JPEG quality will result in meaningful bandwidth savings. I suspect that you are not saving very much, and you may be increasing the bandwidth in some cases (e.g., `postFilePath` points to a PNG). Your costs are a chunk of CPU time, an increased risk of an `OutOfMemoryError`, and the loss of your EXIF tags.

If, instead, the convert-to-70%-JPEG is some sort of data normalization approach, do that work on the server, where you have more CPU power, more disk space, more RAM, and continuous power.

Comment: I see what you mean. As I said the code is 3-4 years old and have already been uploading millions of images to the server. The code scales the images before creating the bitmap, that's why they are not uploaded directly. I just didn't post the scaling code as it's long and I didn't think it was relevant. I'll have to look at the whole thing again.

Comment: @Ambran: Ah, well, if you are also scaling the image, that can easily make a bigger difference in bandwidth consumption. In that case, though, rather than using the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, my guess is that you will need to write the scaled JPEG to a file, so you can re-apply the EXIF headers from the original file. Then, upload from that file.

Comment: Yes, that's what @amuttsch also suggested so that's the way to go. I'm working on that now.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572752/8252521

Answered by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1592398/code-jaff

> Convert the file to bitmap by
>
> ```
> Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decode(filepath + "DSC00021.jpg");
> ```
>
> You can specify options too, look at API [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29)
>
> Or if you want to exchange the meta data from one file to another,
>   [sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/testapidocs/src-html/org/apache/sanselan/sampleUsage/WriteExifMetadataExample.html) will probably be the best choice. This would be much
>   helpful when you manipulating the image, for example re-size.
>
> The [sample code](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/testapidocs/src-html/org/apache/sanselan/sampleUsage/WriteExifMetadataExample.html) will guide you in a right direction.

Comment: The link returns a 404, sanselan is now called Apache Commons Imaging, see https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/

Answer (score 0):

You need to just create a new OutputStream to preserve the Exif Information. There is no need of creating a new File.