# Lost GPS Exif Data after PHP Image Upload

Tags: php, image, upload, gps, exif

When I am uploading an image via smartphone, I am losing my GPS exif data.

Any idea how to upload with GPS exif?

```
if(isset($_FILES['fupload'])) {

  if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(gif)|(png)$/', $_FILES['fupload']['name'])) {

    $filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
    $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];  
    $date = date_create();
    $date = date_timestamp_get($date); 
    $target = $path_to_image_directory . $date . '_' . $filename;

    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
  }
}
```

Comment: are you uploading from an iPhone? there's a known bug (or feature, depending on who you ask) on iOS devices in which some image exif data is stripped from the image when uploading from the iOS device), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297730/image-upload-from-iphone-strips-exif-data

Comment: And this may help you also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928092/android-uploading-image-without-losing-exif-data

Comment: uploading via Samsung Android

Comment: For now I am reading out the exif data from $_FILES['fupload']['name'] and saving the data in a var.
With a perl script I readd the exif data to the uploaded image