MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver() always rotates vertical image to horizontal
In my app, I'm just trying to select multiple images from gallary and show in recyclerview before uploading into server. In recyclerview, the images appear with original orientation. However before uploading into server, it's always rotating all vertical images 90 degree converting vertical image (width * height = 720 * 1280) into horizontal (width * height = 1280 * 720) format. I don't want my vertical images to change orientation at all. I checked all my code, I can conclude below code somehow making the rotation.
  for (int i = 0; i < current_count; i++) {
                    index = i;
                    try {
                        assert getActivity() != null;
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uris.get(i));

                        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

                        Log.d("Logs", "--width, height-" + width + "-" + height + "--");

                        converetdBitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 1280);
                        uploadImagesToDatabase(i, converetdBitmap, current_count);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                       
                    }
                }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        Log.d("Logs", "--width, height-" + width + "-" + height + "--");

        float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }

        Log.d("logs", "-- width, height-" + width + "-" + height + "--");
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

In Log.d("Logs"....) output -- getting 1280 * 720 always while my original pic is of size 720 * 1280. Hence no issues in my function code getResizedBitmap(). The culprit seems to be this command -
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uris.get(i));
Please help me on this. Thank you !

Most image-loading libraries (Glide, Coil, Picasso, etc.) handle this for you.

Glide not handling this for me however. Can you please suggest me the code for glide how can I use that for such orientation problem ??

I'm using below code to upload gallery images into recyclerview. Again FYI, the images are showing perfectly in recyclerview. The problem comes when they are uploaded into server.
Glide.with(context).load(mListPhoto.get(position).getSlidename())
.apply(new RequestOptions()
.fitCenter()
.dontAnimate()
.dontTransform()
.format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
.override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL))
.into(holder.img_photo);

You should not be loading the image in as a Bitmap for uploading to the server. You are losing the EXIF orientation header that tells viewers whether or not to rotate the image. Please upload the JPEG as it is. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44928092/115145 for more.

I used to met a similar issue when I try to display a image from the Camera. The reason for me is that I forgot to change the orientation of the image. Here are two convinent methods I used to read the orientation from File and Uri:
fun File.orientation(): Int {
    try {
        val exif = ExifInterface(absolutePath)
        return when (exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0)) {
            6 -> 90
            3 -> 180
            8 -> 270
            else -> 0
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return 0
}

fun Uri.orientation(context: Context): Int {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        try {
            val exif = ExifInterface(context.contentResolver.openInputStream(this))
            return when (exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0)) {
                6 -> 90
                3 -> 180
                8 -> 270
                else -> 0
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return 0
}

And then, you need to use the Bitmap#rotate() to rotate the Bitmap accordingly.
Also, beware to scale the Bitmap before load it to the memory, since if we load too much memory, it might lead to an OOM. The best practice is to measure image size at first, for example,
 val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
 options.inSampleSize = 1
 uri.decodeBitmap(context, options)

here we use the inJustDecodeBounds to tell the system we only need the size of image instead of loading the entire image to memory.
Image load in Android is somewhat intrigate, you could visit my open source project for details if you are interest: https://github.com/Shouheng88/Compressor .
Best wishes, hope it helps!
